# unable to receive email through contact form here is my code

Tags: php, ajax

I am unable to receive email.here is my code.and i am trying to find my error but i am unable to find.so plzz anybody help me to solve this one.i am doubtful too about my code.here is my code which i have in my php file.my mail()
 functions return true and i have modified my xamp config files.

```
  <?php
    require("connection.php");
    ?>
    <?php

      if(isset($_REQUEST))
      {
          $first = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
          $middle = $_REQUEST['middlename'];
          $last = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
          $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
          $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
          $message =$_REQUEST['message'];
          $query=" INSERT INTO `contact`(`id`,`first-name`, `middle-name`, `last-name`, `email`, `phone`, `message`) VALUES ('','$first','$middle','$last','$email','$phone','$message')";
          $result = mysql_query($query);
          if($result)
          {
            echo "data entered";
          }
          else
          {
            echo "data is not entered";
          }




          $to = "mehmood.asif31@gmail.com";
          $subject = "Message From Contact Us Page";

          $headers = "From:mehmood.asif31@gmail.com \r\n";
          $headers .= "Bcc:mehmood.asif31@gmail.com \r\n";
          $message = '<div style="margin:0 auto; padding:0px;  width:800px">
                              <p style="font:bold 28px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serifl ; color:#006699; padding:0 0 0px 0; ">Feedback Message</p>

                              <div style=" margin:0 0 20px 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; padding:10px; margin:0px; line-height:22px;">
                              <table>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td><strong>Name:</strong></td>
                                      <td>'.$first.'</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td><strong>Email ID:</strong></td>
                                      <td>'.$email.'</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td><strong>Phone No:</strong></td>
                                      <td>'.$phone.'</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td><strong>Message:</strong></td>
                                      <td>'.$message.'</td>
                                  </tr>


                              </table>

                  </div>

                              </div>';

            //echo $message; exit;
          mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);




          unset($_POST);
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: @PaulCrovella i have studied that but don't found my answer there.I have already changed my xamp config file.but i am still getting the same problem.

Comment: and my mail function returns TRUE.

Comment: @AsifMehmood have you checked your error log?

Comment: @Robotia how I can check check error log?

Comment: @AsifMehmood sudo vim /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: Alternatively you can use nano or pico, it doesn't matter which you use

Comment: @Robotia i think i can check error logs when my mail() function returns '0'

Comment: @Asif I know it is returning 1, but have you checked?

Comment: @Robotia  
$resullt= mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); if($result) echo 'sent!'; else echo error_message; i have used this but its printing sent